# How do I split up the for loop into 3 individual data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am currently working with python using Pandas and Matplotlib.pyplot in which I have used existing information to create two different scatter plots of three types of penguins by filtering the data.
It currently works with the for loop, but I want to know how I could achieve the same result using three data frames instead of looping in one.

This is the code I currently have

```
import pandas as pd
URL= 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anibali/c2abc8cab4a2f7b0a6518d11a67c693c/raw/3b1bb5264736bb762584104c9e7a828bef0f6ec8/penguins.csv'
df = pd.read_csv (URL)

#Graph 1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
body_mass = df['body_mass_g']
bill_length = df['bill_length_mm']
species = df['species']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
adelie = df[df['species']== 'Adelie']
chinstrap = df[df['species']== 'Chinstrap']
gentoo = df[df['species']== 'Gentoo']

data = pd.DataFrame({"Species": species, "Body Mass": body_mass, "Bill Length": bill_length})

groups = data.groupby("Species")
for name, group in groups:
    plt.plot(group["Body Mass"], group["Bill Length"], marker="o", linestyle="", label=name)
ax.set_title('Penguin measurements by species')
ax.set_xlabel('Body mass (g)')
ax.set_ylabel('Bill length (mm)')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Graph 2
df['bill_proportion'] = (df['bill_length_mm']/df['bill_depth_mm'])
bill_proportion = df['bill_proportion']
body_mass = df['body_mass_g']
bill_length = df['bill_length_mm']
bill_depth = df['bill_depth_mm']
species = df['species']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
adelie = df[df['species']== 'Adelie']
chinstrap = df[df['species']== 'Chinstrap']
gentoo = df[df['species']== 'Gentoo']

data = pd.DataFrame({"Species": species, "Body Mass": body_mass, "Bill Proportion": bill_proportion})

groups = data.groupby("Species")
for name, group in groups:
    plt.plot(group["Body Mass"], group["Bill Proportion"], marker="o", linestyle="", label=name)
ax.set_title('Penguin proportions by species')
ax.set_xlabel('Body mass (g)')
ax.set_ylabel('Bill proportion (length/width)')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It currently works as a loop, but I want it to use three data frames and not to loop but I am unsure of how to achieve that.
I still want all three data frames to show up in the same scatter plot so it looks exactly the same as it is now, but uses three data frames

Comment: Why are you doing this? The entire thing can be done with 4ish lines of code with https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html. seaborn is a high level api for matplotlib.

Comment: Hi Trent, I didn't even know that existed to be honest with you. I will have a look into that! Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below splits the dataframe into 3, and then plots.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Load data
URL= 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anibali/c2abc8cab4a2f7b0a6518d11a67c693c/raw/3b1bb5264736bb762584104c9e7a828bef0f6ec8/penguins.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(URL)

#Make a bill_proportion column
df['bill_proportion'] = df.bill_length_mm / df.bill_depth_mm

#Split dfs by species
df_adelie = df.loc[df.species == 'Adelie']
df_chinstrap = df.loc[df.species == 'Chinstrap']
df_gentoo = df.loc[df.species == 'Gentoo']

#Plot all 3
x_column = 'body_mass_g'
y_column = 'bill_length_mm'

plt.scatter(df_adelie[x_column], df_adelie[y_column], label='Adelie')
plt.scatter(df_chinstrap[x_column], df_chinstrap[y_column], label='Chinstrap')
plt.scatter(df_gentoo[x_column], df_gentoo[y_column], label='Gentoo')
plt.xlabel(x_column)
plt.ylabel(y_column)
plt.legend()
plt.title(f'{x_column} vs {y_column}')
plt.show()

#Repeat process, using a different y
x_column = 'body_mass_g'
y_column = 'bill_proportion'

plt.scatter(df_adelie[x_column], df_adelie[y_column], label='Adelie')
plt.scatter(df_chinstrap[x_column], df_chinstrap[y_column], label='Chinstrap')
plt.scatter(df_gentoo[x_column], df_gentoo[y_column], label='Gentoo')
plt.xlabel(x_column)
plt.ylabel(y_column)
plt.legend()
plt.title(f'{x_column} vs {y_column}')
plt.show()
```

There's repetition of code, especially for the plotting. You could put some of the code into a function.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I needed, You have been a huge help!